# Bug ao adicionar elementos à lista e transforma-la em string

Tags: python, string, lista, for, jogos

Estou tento dor de cabeça no decorrer de um mini-projeto para desenvolver um jogo da forca, na função que retornaria a string contendo a palavra escondida, mostrando apenas as letras adivinhadas. Já tentei de tudo, já pesquisei sobre transformar em string com a função str() e join(), caso tenham uma outra sugestão para o código, também vai ajudar muito. Segue o código:

```
def char_check(char, word):
    newWord_list = []
    newWord_ = ''
    for i in range(0, len(char)-1):
        if char == word[i]:
            newWord_list.append(char)
        else:
            newWord_list.append('_'))
    newWord_ = ''.join(newWord_list)
    return newWord_
```

Comment: `char` é para ser apenas uma letra, certo? Se sim, a função não está entrando no loop já que `len(char)-1`=0

Answer (score 2):

Além do já explicado sobre o laço de iteração...

```
for i in range(0, len(char) - 1):
```

...que deveria ser modificado para...

```
for i in range(0, len(word) - 1):
```

... seu código está desproporcionalmente verboso a dificuldade da tarefa a ser realizada.

Use uma [expressão regular](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html#module-re) para esconder as letras ainda não descobertas de uma string.

A função [`re.sub(pattern, repl, s, count=0, flags=0)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html#re.sub) faz a substituição na string `s` dos caracteres encontrados pelo padrão de correspondência `pattern` pela string `repl`.
O padrão de correspondência **`[^`***`caracteres`***`]`** instrui a expressão a corresponder todos os caracteres exceto aos caracteres entre **`[^`** e **`]`**.
A flag [`re.IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) executa uma correspondência que não diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas.

A função [`re.escape(pattern)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html#re.escape) escapa caracteres especiais no padrão `pattern` aqui usada para prevenir a injeção de [metacaracteres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) no padrão para evitar trapaças.

```
import re

def char_check(char, word):
    return re.sub(fr"[^{re.escape(char)}]", "_", word, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Exemplo:

```
>>> print(char_check("p","Paralelepipedo"))
P_______p_p___
```

Teste o exemplo abaixo no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/9S31ie)

```
import re
import random

def char_check(char, word):
    return re.sub(fr"[^{re.escape(char)}]", "_", word, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    
    
palavra = random.choice(["Python", "Haskell", "Javascript", "Scheme", "Lisp", "Visual Basic", "Clipper", "Assembly", "Cobol", "Forth" ])
tentativas = " "

print("Você tem cinco tentativas.\n")
print(char_check(tentativas, palavra))
print("\n")
for i in range(1,6):
    tentativas += input(f"Tentativa {i}: ")
    jogada = char_check(tentativas, palavra)
    print(jogada)
    if jogada == palavra:
        print("!!!TEMOS UM VENCEDOR!!!")
        break
else:
    print("Você morreu enforcado")

#Você tem cinco tentativas.

#_____
   
#Tentativa 1: p
#_____
#Tentativa 2: m
#_____
#Tentativa 3: o
#_o___
#Tentativa 4: frth
#Forth
#!!!TEMOS UM VENCEDOR!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema do seu código está no bloco de repetição. Você está utilizando o tamanho da string `char` — que teoricamente deve conter apenas um caractere — na função `range()` como ponto de parada, quando deveria estar utilizando o tamanho da string `word`.

```
for i in range(0, len(word) - 1):
    ...
```

Além disso, um outro problema do seu código, ainda na mesma linha, é a utilização da subtração `-1` no ponto de parada da função. Você não deve subtrair o valor do `stop`, porque a função define esse valor como o seu limite "definitivo". Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
list(range(5))      # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
list(range(5 - 1))  # [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Dito isso, o seu código deveria ficar assim:

```
def char_check(char, word):

    newWord_list = []
    newWord_ = ''
    
    # O valor padrão de "start" é zero. Sendo assim, não precisa especificá-lo.
    for i in range(len(word)): 

        if char == word[i]:
            newWord_list.append(char)
        else:
            newWord_list.append('_')

    newWord_ = ''.join(newWord_list)
    return newWord_
```

Além disso, é possível melhorar ainda mais a sua função, sem precisar criar uma nova lista. Para isso, percorra cada caractere da sua string através do laço `for` e verifique se a letra é a mesma de `char`. Se sim, adicione-a para a nova string. Se não, adicione a string `"_"`. Veja como ficaria:

```
def char_check(char, word):

    new_word = ""

    for letter in word:
        if char == letter: new_word += char
        else: new_word += "_"

    return new_word
```

É possível também fazer tudo isso em apenas uma única linha, utilizando [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), da seguinte forma:

```
 def char_check(char, word):

    return "".join([char if char == letter else "_" for letter in word])
```